# Do stalks determine a sheafification?

Tags: sheaf-theory

Today I was thinking about an explicit example of sheafification, namely the sheafification of the presheaf of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. I am working with sheafification as the sheaf of sections of the corresponding étalé space.

I knew before starting that this sheafification is isomorphic to the sheaf of continuous functions. For illustrative purposes I checked this by manually constructing the sheaf of sections for the étalé space, then showing it is isomorphic to the sheaf of continuous functions and also by showing that the sheaf of continuous functions satisfies the universal property of the sheafification. After seeing this formally, I decided this is intuitive because locally, germs on the sheaf of continuous functions should look the same as the germs on the presheaf of continuous and bounded functions, and when we sheafify we just add in things that can be made from germs that were missing. What I am wondering now is if this is a coherent way to predict or intuit what a sheafification should look like. Namely, I am wondering

1. Is it true that for any presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ and its sheafification $\mathcal{F}^{+}$, $\mathcal{F}_x \cong \mathcal{F}^{+}_{x}$ for all $x$?
2. Is it true that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a presheaf and $\mathcal{G}$ is a sheaf such that $\mathcal{F}_x \cong \mathcal{G}_x$ for all $x$, then $\mathcal{G} \cong \mathcal{F}^{+}$

I am aware I am only thinking about seperated presheaves, which could be a huge flaw in my reasoning.

Edit: I suppose what I am trying to do is find a provable formalization that expresses my intuition that “if a sheaf is a presheaf who’s sections are determined by local data, then if a presheaf and a sheaf share the same most-local data (germs/stalks) and also have the same criterion for compatibility, the sheafification of the presheaf should coincide with the sheaf”

Comment: 2. is certainly false: not all fibre bundles are trivial.

Comment: An equivalent way of saying that 2. is false is that there exist non-isomorphic sheaves with isomorphic stalks: [main](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43314/11619), [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/596622/11619). What does hold is that if the isomorphisms between the stalks are induced by a homomorphism of sheaves, then the two sheaves are isomorphic.

Comment: Hmm ok so the isomorphisms need to be such that the map they induce on étalé spaces is continuous, and it just so happens in the case I was exploring I got lucky and they did

Comment: On the other hand 1. is true. As the previous comment explained, 2. is false but if you have $\varphi:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ which induces isomorphisms $\varphi_x:\mathcal{F}_x\overset\sim\to\mathcal{G}_x$, then $\mathcal{F}^+\simeq\mathcal{G}^+$. In particular, if $\mathcal{G}$ is already a sheaf, then $\mathcal{F}^+\simeq\mathcal{G}$. No need to assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is separated here.

Comment: @Roland I think this is the type of thing I am looking for. To show $\mathcal{F}^{+} \cong \mathcal{G}^{+}$ I suspect we want to set up a commutative square using the universal properties of both sheafifications and the map $\varphi \colon \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$, then use the induced isomorphisms on stalks to show induced isomorphisms on stalks between sheafifications? Then applying what Jyrki said, these sheaves must be isomorphic, then the next thing you mentioned is clear, but how to get the induced isomorphisms on stalks between sheafifications?

Comment: With more category theory experience it may be immediate that the diagram I describe yields a stalk diagram (this much I buy since taking stalks should be a functor?), but then what forces the other isomorphism?

Comment: Well sheafification is a functor, so a map of presheaves $\varphi:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ induces a map between their associated sheaves. The identification $\mathcal{F}\simeq\mathcal{F}^+$ is natural so you indeed have a commutative square with 4 isomorphisms between $\mathcal{F, G}$ and their sheafification.